# Default constructor getting executed many times when tried to load records in Hibernate 5.x

Tags: hibernate

Could some one please help me to understand, Why default constructor getting executed many times when tried to load records in Hibernate 5.x

**Persistence class**

```
public class Customer {

    private int cid;
    private String cphone;
    private String ccity;
    private String cemail;

    public Customer() {
        System.out.println("**Default Constructor**");
    }

    public Customer(String cphone, String ccity, String cemail) {
        this.cphone = cphone;
        this.ccity = ccity;
        this.cemail = cemail;
    }

    public int getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(int cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public String getCphone() {
        return cphone;
    }

    public void setCphone(String cphone) {
        this.cphone = cphone;
    }

    public String getCcity() {
        return ccity;
    }

    public void setCcity(String ccity) {
        this.ccity = ccity;
    }

    public String getCemail() {
        return cemail;
    }

    public void setCemail(String cemail) {
        this.cemail = cemail;
    }
}
```

**Steps to load Records**
[image]

**Logs**
[image: Console Logs Screenshot]

Note: Tried with SQLServer 2014 and Hibernate 5.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The first call

As of Hibernate 5.3.7 the **first** one happens during `SessionFactory` initialization process:

```
if ( identifierGetter != null && constructor != null ) {
    // use the id value of a newly instantiated instance as the unsaved-value
    final Serializable defaultValue = (Serializable) identifierGetter.get( instantiate( constructor ) );
    return new IdentifierValue( defaultValue );
}
```

Seems it figures out which value of the `@Id` field indicates that an `@Entity` is unsaved.

See [`UnsavedValueFactory`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/internal/UnsavedValueFactory.java#L68).

### The second call

You're using [`Session#load`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load-java.lang.Class-java.io.Serializable-), which returns a proxy for the entity assuming it exists.

The proxy class is a sublcass of `@Entity`

So the proxy class' constructor calls super constructor. Hence the **second** call

### The third call

Then you're forcing `Hibernate` to initialize the entity (you call `getCemail()`).
`Hibernate` issues the `sql` statement and then initializes  [`AbstractLazyInitializer#target`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/proxy/AbstractLazyInitializer.java#L37). This is the **third** call to the constructor

---

To better understand what is going on I would recommend you to debug it.

Put a breakpoint at the default constructor and watch the stack trace.